# why can't I Inject directive into my test cases

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I could able to inject almost everything in the `beforeEach(inject(beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_,_mycustomService_,_$log_)`  in Jasmine

etc, But I can't inject a directive ?

I would get error like http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=myCustomDirectiveProvider%20%3C-%20myCustomDirective

Should this not possible with AngularJS ? Is this the reason why the unit testing of directive is little different style ( by that I meant the $compile option) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives aren't injectable anywhere in angular, only providers (services, factories, values, constants, etc.).

In order to test a directive, you need to ensure the module in which the directive is defined has been loaded with the `module()` function, (it'll also need to be referenced in your karma config), then you can compile a piece of DOM and ensure everything behaves as you expect.

Rather than go into a full example here, I'll advise you to do your own research and google "testing angular directives".

Comment: Just a guess Ed but I'll wager the OP has already searched for "testing angular directives"... Not much help telling someone to google it really is it?